# How to give table white background color - Bootstrap, Yii

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I've modified the general Yii Crud generated index.php to *not* display the side menu and instead display a table. I've done this by overriding the default layout and by creating a column3.php This view file looks like this

```
    <?php $this->beginContent('//layouts/main'); ?>
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span3">

            <table class="table table-bordered">
    <form action="<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('recipient/processpayment', array('id'=>$id)) ?>" method="post" >
        <tr class="primary"><td> <h4>List Summary </h4> </td></tr>
        <tr ><td>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $numpeople; ?> Recipient(s)
        </td></tr>

        <tr ><td>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;Total Due: &nbsp;<?php echo $totaldue ?> Rwf
        </td></tr>          
    </form>

  </table>


        </div><!-- sidebar span3 -->
        <div class="span9">
        <div class="main">
            <?php echo $content; ?>
        </div><!-- content -->
    </div>
</div>
<?php $this->endContent();  ?>
```

Unfortunately the side of my screen is a grey color and I've realized that the table itself is simply composed of a couple of lines and text (meaning it is see-through). I'd like to change the background color of the table to be white - any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSS

```
.table,
.table tr,
.table td {
    background-color: white !important;
}
```